# Exclude An item from mapping

Tags: reactjs

I want to explicitly exclude imgvid from mapping and pass it to PostContainer Component.It Causes Rerendering of Component.I want imgvid to pass from PostList to PostContainer.But without this double mappings (in postContainer and postList) Iam unable to correctly fetch my data in the .jsx page.But this double mapping causes rerendering of the .jsx page and it causes doubling of my content in the front page.

```
<React.Fragment>
  <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
    {posts.map(item => (
      <PostContainer
        isStylefeed={isStylefeed}
        likeAccess={likeAccess}
        commentAccess={commentAccess}
        wowAccess={wowAccess}
        yayAccess={yayAccess}
        post={item}
        imgvid={imgvid}
        key={item[ID]}
        loadPosts={loadPosts}
        currentCommunity={currentCommunity}
        currentCommunityID={currentCommunityID}
        handlePosts={handlePosts}
        getOutfits={getOutfits}
        isMember={isMember}
      />
    ))}
  </div>
</React.Fragment>
```

//PostContainer.jsx

```
return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div>
      {imgvid
        && imgvid.map(item => (
          <Posts
            likeAccess={likeAccess}
            commentAccess={commentAccess}
            wowAccess={wowAccess}
            isStylefeed={isStylefeed}
            yayAccess={yayAccess}
            handleRedirectOutfitPage={this.handleRedirectOutfitPage}
            currentCommunity={currentCommunity}
            toggleFlagModal={this.toggleFlagModal}
            handleFlaggedPostReasonChange={this.handleFlaggedPostReasonChange}
            deletePost={this.deletePost}
            handledeleteComment={this.handledeleteComment}
            getCurrentProfile={this.getCurrentProfile}
            onReadOnlyProfile={this.onReadOnlyProfile}
            updatePost={this.updatePost}
            handleUpdatePost={this.handleUpdatePost}
            toggleUpdate={this.toggleUpdate}
            toggleOptions={this.toggleOptions}
            handleFlagPost={this.handleFlagPost}
            flagModal={flagModal}
            post={post}
            likesProfile={likesProfile}
            followersProfile={followersProfile}
            outfits={outfits}
            readOnlyProfileModal={readOnlyProfileModal}
            modalUpdate={modalUpdate}
            postText={text}
            postOptions={postOptions}
            getAllCommentsByPostId={this.getAllCommentsByPostId}
            currentCommunityID={currentCommunityID}
            outfitChanged={outfitChanged}
            getLatestPost={this.getLatestPost}
            toggleMessageModal={this.toggleMessageModal}
            messageModal={messageModal}
            refData={refData}
            showflagModal={showflagModal}
            checkFlaggedOrNot={this.checkFlaggedOrNot}
            flagged={flagged}
            isMember={isMember}
            imgvid={item}
            email={email}
          />
        ))}
    </div>
  </React.Fragment>
);
```

Comment: Hi can you explain some more as to what you are trying to do ? also what is the structure of a post object ?

Comment: In addition to Muljayan request, if possible, share the `PostContainer`'s component code with us, the issue might be there!

Comment: I Added the PostContainer Code here

Comment: You should try using key attribute whenever you're building the component using array.map. That could resolve lot of issues with re-rendering.

Comment: How Iam New to React